# Trying to clone Attachment to new record via trigger Code not working

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, attachment

I'm trying to clone an attachment on an opportunity to a custom case object via a trigger.  My code is creating the case but not cloning the attachment.  Is there anything I can do to get this to work?

```
trigger RDAssessmentCreation on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
list<PlatformCase__c> lstPC = new List<PlatformCase__c>();
list<map<Date,PlatformCase__c>> lstmapPC = new list<map<Date,PlatformCase__c>>();


    list<Opportunity> lstOpp = [Select id, Accountid,Filing_Deadline__c, Projected_Delivery_Date__c, CloseDate, StageName, Generate_Projects__c, RecordTypeId,(Select Id, ProductID__c,Jurisdiction__c,Quantity,ServiceDate From Opportunitylineitems) From Opportunity
                               ];


    for(opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(opp.StageName =='3 - Assessment Request' && opp.RecordTypeId == '012M00000004qsD') {
            lstPC.add(new PlatformCase__c(Opportunity__c = opp.Id,
                                          Subject__c = 'Test R&D Case',
                                          Status__c = 'New',
                                          Category__c = 'Data Support',
                                          Description__c = 'Test Add Case Attachment'));
            list<Attachment> lstAttachment = [SELECT id FROM Attachment WHERE parentID IN :lstOpp];
            Attachment newAtt = new Attachment(ParentId = opp.id);
        }
    }
    insert lstPC;
}
```

Comment: where's the insert of newAtt?

Comment: I added that prior to insert Case and I'm getting the error variable does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to agree with @crop1645 on this you are definitely missing your insert of your new attachments. To expand on that it looks like you want to include multiple attachments as well so you will want to loop through your attachments and most likely clone them, the reason for that is if attachments are deleted from the new object you most likely wouldn't want them to be removed from your original opportunity. Hope this helps.

```
List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();

for(Attachment file : Trigger.new) {
   Attachment newFile = file.clone();
   newFile.ParentId = opp.Id;
   attachments.add(newFile);
   }
// finally, insert the cloned attachments
insert attachments;
```

**Updated Code Section**

```
>     for(opportunity opp : trigger.new){
>         if(opp.StageName =='3 - Assessment Request' && opp.RecordTypeId == '012M00000004qsD') {
>             lstPC.add(new PlatformCase__c(Opportunity__c = opp.Id,
>                                           Subject__c = 'Test R&D Case',
>                                           Status__c = 'New',
>                                           Category__c = 'Data Support',
>                                           Description__c = 'Test Add Case Attachment'));
>         }
>         List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
> 
> for(Attachment file : Trigger.new) {    Attachment newFile =
> file.clone();    newFile.ParentId = opp.Id;   
> attachments.add(newFile);    }
> 
> insert attachments;
>         insert lstPC; } }
```

Comment: I'm having issues placing this statement in the trigger. What else do I need for this to work?  I'm getting the error that opp.Id variable does not exist.

Comment: Where did you place this code in your file, it will need to be within the scope of opp.Id

Comment: See updated code section.